# Rolling 182-day average

Tags: r, loops, average, rolling-computation

I have a dataset with multiple sites and sampling years, with a score for every day of the year. For example, SiteA has 40 years of data with a value for every day, and sampling year defined as Sampling.Year. To make it confusing our sampling year is July-June so takes the form of 2016-2017. 
For example:

```
SiteName Sampling.Year   Date    Score 
A        2015-2016               1  
A        2015-2016               5  
A        2015-2016               2 
A        2016-2017               3 
A        2016-2017               12 
A        2016-2017               6 
B        2015-2016               9 
B        2015-2016               2 
B        2015-2016               1 
B        2016-2017               4 
B        2016-2017               1 
B        2016-2017               7
```

I want to apply a rolling 182-day average across this data to find the maximum (182-day average) score for each site/Sampling.Year combination. The outcome would be, e.g.:

```
Site Sampling.Year   MaxAve StartDate
A    2016-2017       7.5    01/10/2016 
A    2017-2018       6.0    12/12/2017 
B    2016-2017       2.3    13/11/2016
B    2017-2018       4.2    09/09/2017
```

I have saved a sample dataset here:
[Sample data](http://www.mediafire.com/file/7rmqrz6zczjorla/DailyScore.csv/file). 
I want to use a loop code (because I am a novice and i'm not sure of a better way) along the lines of this, but it's the grouping of sites and years that I'm finding tricky. I would ideally like to have the moving average able to be exported as a new dataframe with start and end date (or at least start date) for each window so we can check it against weather conditions at the time.

```
Moving_Average_Function <- function(arr, n=182){
  res = arr
  for(i in n:length(arr)){
    res[i] = mean(arr[(i-n+1):i])
  }
  res
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to use external libraries, you could use `group_by()` from the dplyr package, and the `roll_mean()` function from the RcppRoll package.  RcppRoll has a set of fast flexible functions for calculating moving averages.

I would also tend to convert your DATE column to a date class so it arranges smoothly.

```
library(dplyr)  # I would typically use library(tidyverse) to load both dplyr and tidyr (among other related packages)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
library(RcppRoll)

my_data <- data.table::fread("DailyScore.csv")  # easy way to load a data frame from file

my_data2 <- my_data %>%
      mutate(DATE = dmy(DATE)) %>% # Converting to Date format
      pivot_longer(H1:T2, 
                   names_to = "Sensor",
                   values_to = "data"
                   )  %>% # convert column names to data
      group_by(STATION, Sensor) %>%  # so you don't average by site.
      arrange(STATION, DATE) %>%  # to be sure you are in order for the rolling mean 
                                  #  The STATION argument isn't necessary, but helps for display
      mutate(Mean_182 = roll_meanr(data, 182)) %>%  # New column with your rolling mean
      pivot_wider(names_from = Sensor, values_from = c(data, Mean_182))  # converts back to original "wide" format

my_data2[180:195,]

# # A tibble: 16 x 14
# # Groups:   STATION [1]
# STATION SITENAME Sampling.Year DATE       data_H1  data_I1 data_H2 data_P2 data_T2 Mean_182_H1
# <chr>   <chr>    <chr>         <date>       <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>       <dbl>
#       1 Site A  Site A   1979-1980     1980-06-28    2.85 1.06e- 9    2.10   0.762    2.85       NA   
# 2 Site A  Site A   1979-1980     1980-06-29    2.79 1.62e-12    2.06   0.744    2.79       NA   
# 3 Site A  Site A   1979-1980     1980-06-30    2.75 1.00e-11    2.04   0.732    2.75        2.70
# 4 Site A  Site A   1980-1981     1980-07-01    2.72 1.00e-11    2.01   0.724    2.72        2.71
# 5 Site A  Site A   1980-1981     1980-07-02    2.70 1.00e-11    2.00   0.720    2.70        2.73
# 6 Site A  Site A   1980-1981     1980-07-03    2.68 1.00e-11    1.98   0.718    2.68        2.74
# 7 Site A  Site A   1980-1981     1980-07-04    2.67 1.00e-11    1.97   0.719    2.67        2.75
# 8 Site A  Site A   1980-1981     1980-07-05    2.65 1.11e- 9    1.95   0.708    2.65        2.76
# 9 Site A  Site A   1980-1981     1980-07-06    2.62 2.77e-10    1.93   0.703    2.62        2.76
# 10 Site A  Site A   1980-1981     1980-07-07    2.60 3.18e-12    1.92   0.700    2.60        2.77
# 11 Site A  Site A   1980-1981     1980-07-08    2.59 1.00e-11    1.90   0.701    2.59        2.79
# 12 Site A  Site A   1980-1981     1980-07-09    2.59 1.00e-11    1.89   0.706    2.59        2.80
# 13 Site A  Site A   1980-1981     1980-07-10    2.59 1.00e-11    1.89   0.713    2.59        2.81
# 14 Site A  Site A   1980-1981     1980-07-11    2.59 1.00e-11    1.88   0.722    2.59        2.82
# 15 Site A  Site A   1980-1981     1980-07-12    2.60 1.00e-11    1.88   0.731    2.60        2.83
# 16 Site A  Site A   1980-1981     1980-07-13    2.60 1.00e-11    1.87   0.741    2.60        2.84
# # ... with 4 more variables: Mean_182_I1 <dbl>, Mean_182_H2 <dbl>, Mean_182_P2 <dbl>, Mean_182_T2 <dbl>
```

Couple things to keep in mind, which will affect how you set this up.

1. In general rolling averages will return NA when they don't have a complete data set.  So with a 182-day average, you'll get a series of 181 NA's before your first complete average.
2. You'll want to figure out how you want to handle the roll over parts- especially with a long period rolling average, if you don't want to mix sampling years, you'll have about half the year without data.

Comment: how would I go about doing the same rolling average for all categories (H1, I1, H2, P2, T2) at the same time? I would then like to select the highest score for T1 for each Sampling.Year and export to a new data frame with associated average for each of the other categories for that date (doesn't matter if it isn't the max of each of those).

Comment: If you wanted a new table without the original you could use `summarize_all()` instead of `mutate()` for the rolling average, you wouldn't need the pivot functions in that case.  Both are from the dplyr package.

Comment: Ah that's very cool thank you!! I've learnt a lot from your responses, thanks so much for taking the time. I have another question based on the same data but I might make a new post so it doesn't get confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Using loops would be very inefficient for such operations. You can use some dedicated functions which allow you to perform this by group and use `zoo::rollmean` to get rolling mean.

```
library(dplyr)

DailyScore %>% 
  group_by(SITENAME, Sampling.Year) %>% 
  summarise(max_average = max(zoo::rollmean(Score, 182)))
```

Comment: Thank you Ronak! Another stupid question (sorry) but how do I restrict it to a unique variable, e.g. column I (variable T2) in the sample data set?

Comment: @CatN Do you mean you want to apply it to only `T2` variable? You can use `T2` instead of `Score`, `summarise(max_average = max(zoo::rollmean(T2, 182)))`